# how to attach a picture to the position of an array? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm creating a script capable of display 5 images when pressing a button. 
I need to insert in the positions of the array 5 images, something like;

```
array [0] = image1; 
array [1] = image2; 

etc ...
```

When the user presses the button "change", the image 1 (displayed on screen) is replaced by the second image attached to the second position of the array.

```
<style type="text/css">
#button1 
{
border:2px #333 solid;   
padding:20px;
width:250px;
-webkit-border-radius:40px;
-moz-border-radius:40px;
border-radius:40px;
}
</style>
<div align="center">
<br><br><br><br>
<img src="Koala.jpg" id="im1" width="300px" height="200px">
<img src="Casa.jpg" id="im1" width="300px" height="200px">
<img src="Tulipani.jpg" id="im1" width="300px" height="200px">
<img src="Pinguini.jpg" id="im1" width="300px" height="200px">
<img src="Deserto.jpg" id="im1" width="300px" height="200px">
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="cambia" onclick="im()" height="50">
</div>
<script>

var array = new Array();

function im()
{
console.log("on");
}

</script>
```

but this code display all 5 image.

Until now I have realized the html style, but I don't know of  method or property that will let me proceed. Could you help me?

Comment: What is your HTML? You need a counter variable (`i`) and on each click you change the image's `src` attribute to the URI specified in `array[++i]` (pay attention to the bounds though!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img src="Deserto.jpg" id="im1" width="300px" height="200px">
<!-- only one <img>. And btw. never use the same id multiple times -->
<br><br>
<input type="button" id="button1" value="cambia" onclick="im()" height="50">
```

Then the JavaScript:

```
 var
 current = 0,
 images = [];

 images.push('Koala.jpg');
 images.push('Casa.jpg');
 images.push('Tulipani.jpg');
 images.push('Pinguini.jpg');
 images.push('Deserto.jpg');


 function im() {
   current += 1;
   if (current >= images.length) {
     current = 0;
   }
   document.getElementById('im1').src = images[current];
 }
```

Comment: This is very incredible solution.

Answer (score 1):

you can do that
array [0] = $('#im1').attr('src');
array [1] = $('#im2').attr('src');
and change id of picture in html

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle for you: [jsfiddle.net/kx5nX/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/kx5nX/1/)

Basically you want to use the following function to toggle the class `current` on each picture in turn. With the following HTML (notice I added the `current` class to the first img)

```
<div align="center">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <img src="Koala.jpg" id="im1" width="300px" height="200px" class="current" alt="Koala">
  <img src="Casa.jpg" id="im2" width="300px" height="200px" alt="Casa">
  <img src="Tulipani.jpg" id="im3" width="300px" height="200px" alt="Tulipani">
  <img src="Pinguini.jpg" id="im4" width="300px" height="200px" alt="Pinguini">
  <img src="Deserto.jpg" id="im5" width="300px" height="200px" alt="Deserto">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" id="button1" value="cambia" onclick="im()" height="50"> 
</div>
```

> **Note:** I've changed the `id`s in your images to be unique as per the HTML spec.

You can define the `im()` function like this:

```
function im() {
  this.imgs = this.imgs || document.querySelectorAll("div > img");
  var l = this.imgs.length,
      img;

  this.i = !this.i ? 1 : (this.i < l ? this.i : 0);

  for(;img = imgs[--l];)
    img.classList.remove('current');

  imgs[this.i++].classList.add('current');
}
```

Then all you need to do is add a bit of css to make the `current` class show itself, while all other images are hidden:

```
div > img:not(.current) {
  display: none;
}
```